# Measure Square (width, height)

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I have a situation where i find some contours that result in a square, this is square is not in a 90º angle. How can i transform it for measure his Width and Height?

here is a example image:
[square detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k53ET.jpg)

And here is my code that draw the Square:

```
CvInvoke.Polylines(copyImg, squares[i], true, new MCvScalar(0, 255, 0), 1, LineType.FourConnected);
```

Comment: You can compute the `minAreaRect` of your contour, and then you have the `width` and `height` of the `RotatedRect`

Comment: @Miki But when i use minAreaRect it result on this https://s22.postimg.org/8w3247r2p/Capture.png

Comment: @Miki i need to align the 4 points i think